# Piping buffer through a command, handling failure gracefully

Tags: external-command, formatting

I want to be able to lint my code from within vim, using tools like `clang-format` and `yapf` and I'd rather do this without installing a more complex plugin.

I can pipe the current buffer through a text processing command:

```
:%!clang-format
```

However, if my buffer contents results in an error for the external command, my buffer will be replaced with *stderr* output and I will have to reset this manually (with an undo).

Is there any way to only replace the buffer if the text-processing command returns exit success?

I know I can undo but, ideally, I would like to be able to run this on vim exit but I can't risk the buffer being clobbered. This has other applications than linting, so a more general solution than just *install the xxx plugin* would be appreciated, if anyone knows of one!

Comment: might be relevant: https://gist.github.com/romainl/d2ad868afd7520519057475bd8e9db0c

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hmmm. Good question. Is there really not a Vim mechanism for dealing with this? I can't recall seeing one.

If there's not I was able to leverage Bash semantics to get something to work. I'm using `sort` as an example command as it's a common filter and easy to make fail...

**Valid** invocation:

```
:%!sort -n 2> /dev/null || cat %
```

*Result*: the buffer contents are sorted.

**Invalid** invocation (simulating any error condition):

```
:%!sort -x 2> /dev/null || cat %
```

*Result*: the buffer contents are undisturbed.

So the general pattern is:

```
:%!{your command and args} 2> /dev/null || cat %
```

`2> /dev/null` discards any error messages (assuming they are properly emitted from *stderr*). Alternatively, you could send error output to a temporary file so at least you can diagnose things when there's a failure. Just replace `/dev/null` with a valid path/filename.

A hack? Not in the context of Bash. In this Vim context...perhaps. Should be pretty steady for any filtering as long as you're not doing anything else with redirects or the like.

This can, of course, be made a little more convenient by integrating it into a user command.

Comment: the `|| cat %` bit was what I needed. I had already tried redirecting the output. Upvoted. Thank you

Comment: This is what I use btw: https://github.com/arp242/dotfiles/blob/master/vim/vimrc#L497-L501 – a little bit of ceremony around it to make it a bit more smooth. The undjoin doesn't quite work as I'd like, but haven't really looked at it much. Also, errors fail very silently which isn't super-great.

Comment: It was useful, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not really a plugin, but you'll need a few lines of VimScript. Sort of this:

```
let result = systemlist('clang-format', bufnr())
if v:shell_error != 0
    throw "failure"
endif
call deletebufline('', 1, '$')
call setline(1, result)
```

Then pack it into a function, bind it to some key etc.etc.